# Why is DanMachi manga slower than Anime?

Tags: danmachi

Im currently watching the anime (ongoing) on the latest episode, and really turned into it.. I wanted to read the manga as most of the times it's ahead of the anime.. But its a different scenario in this case. Then, Where should I read or see what happens further?

Comment: Light novels of this series are more updated: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is_It_Wrong_to_Try_to_Pick_Up_Girls_in_a_Dungeon%3F

Comment: To complement W. Are's comment, *DanMachi* is originated from the Light Novels, then adapted to both anime and manga. The original source is the Light Novel.